# Deploy jsp project via IIS

Tags: jsp, iis, deployment

I had finish my jsp project by using Netbeans IDE with glassfish server. But the problem I faced now is how can I deploay it to site and access via another computer? I am trying to use IIS but I have no ideas to do it. Can someone please me. Thank you.

Comment: Your problem is not very clear to me. Do you want to know how to run Glashfish behind IIS or how to deploy a site to a public server in general?

Comment: Dear @Jeroen, actually I would like to know the way to run my web application in other computer instead of only using localhost in developer computer.